# What's an "amagat"? How is it different from the Loschmidt Number?

Tags: physical-chemistry, terminology, units

At class, we were (briefly) taught about the *Loschmidt Number/Constant ($n_0$)*, which isn't really different from the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loschmidt_constant),

> The **Loschmidt constant** or **Loschmidt's number** (symbol: $n_0$) is the number of particles (atoms or molecules) of an ideal gas in a given volume (the *number density*).

Furthermore, it says,

> It is usually quoted at *standard temperature and pressure*, the 2010 **CODATA** recommended value is  per cubic metre at $0 °C$ and 1 atm.

<sub>(Yes, I know [*STP* is currently defined at 1 bar pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure), and not 1 atm. Since this isn't my main question, I'm bringing it up here: Is the Wikipedia definition of the Loschmidt number inaccurate? Should it be defined at 1 bar, instead?)</sub>

Reading on, I saw,

> Being a measure of number density, the Loschmidt constant is used to define the **amagat**, a practical unit of number density for gases and other substances:
>
> 1 amagat = $n_0$ = $2.686 7805(24)$ x $\mathrm{10^{25}}$ per cubic meter,
>
> such that the Loschmidt constant is exactly 1 amagat.

To begin with, I've **never heard** of an "amagat" [<--- I mean the unit, not the law named after the same person]. Yes, this may be the result of my shortcomings as a high-schooler with limited (almost pitiful, really) exposure to physical chemistry...but what bugs me more, is that I still can't wrap my head around it even now.

Including the [Wikipedia definition for the amagat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amagat) before I continue,

> An amagat is a practical unit of number density. Although it can be applied to any substance at any conditions, it is defined as the number of ideal gas molecules per unit volume at 1 atm and 0 °C.

We already have the good ol' Loschmidt Number...so why introduce *another* term/unit that is (seemingly) defined the *same* way, has the *same* value and carries the same (SI) *units*?

Besides, what's with the "*...practical unit of number density.*" bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any of these particular units before so I could be mistaken, but I imagine it is similar to how we don't say "I have 3 Avogadro's Numbers of water" we would say "I have 3 moles of water". We very well could describe amounts by explicitly naming multiples of the constant, but we instead defined a new unit so that we could describe things more easily.